# Storings some fields in local storage

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to store every created field in localStorage to get the ID's for later use.

This is a cordova app.

I'm creating field with javascript. An outside DIV, and input field and a button.
This input field and button has to be stored in localStorage for later use.

I have stored the div group ID,  input Field ID and button ID in localStorage. I do not know if this is the best solution, but if not, then I would appreciate some pointers.

This is how I store it:

```
localStorage.setItem('inputGroup', 'input_area_group_' + id + '');
localStorage.setItem('inputField', 'input_field_' + id + '')
localStorage.setItem('delButton', 'delBtn_' + id + '');
```

Now.

This is the first time I'm acctualy using localStorage, so I do not have that big clue about it, but at least I'm trying.

When I store these 3 values into local storage and create another field with the excact same values. Will those then overwrite the other results or will there be an array with all the results in "inputGroup" f.eks? Like if I have 40 fields, I would like to have 40 values in "inputGroup" of localstorage.

This is because when I have created these fields, I would like to delete one of them if I want to. And then I tought that I could fetch the ID in localstorage that match the ID of the button that I pressed.

Is this a viable solution?
If not, then I'm happy with some pointers to what I could use that would make this much better.

Comment: I use something called [jsql](https://github.com/Pamblam/jSQL) for long term database storage in the Cordova apps I maintain for work.

Comment: You may be going about this the wrong way. If your fields, groups, and buttons are exactly the same, and the only thing that changes is the id, then use a class with a click listener on your delete button. When you press the delete button it removes the relative container based on the button you pressed. You don't need to save each unique id name of each field, group or button for this, even if you're doing an offline app. See my quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/p3zjdu0g/

Comment: Thanks for that one JM-AGMS. This means that I did it correctly the first time I tried it.
The problem now is that my code works in JSFiddle, but not in my Cordova app. 
This is the output of my HTML code and the JS i work with: https://jsfiddle.net/uLm73new/4/

Comment: That works, it looks to be a problem on getting it to work on Cordova. I would recommend you open the console under your Cordova app and see if you have any errors there. If you're still unable to figure it out, start a new question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is a dictionary, so the first part (the key) is unique.  The second part, the value is tied to the key.  Changing the value portion will replace, not add a new one. You could change the key value if you wanted instead.

Or you, can store the value as a delimited string, concatenating the new string each time.  (However, concatenation is generally a slow operation).   In this case, you could take the concatenated string and convert it to a JavaScript array.

Comment: Okey. My understanding of JavaScript is like 30%, so I will try to understand this. So what you think is a better solution is to, that every time I create a new "div" with input and button I should push this to an array, and then save the array in localStorage since the value gets replaced.

So If it is stored in an array, and the array is stored in localstorage, then I would always have my ID's?

Comment: if you store an array in localstorage you have to stringify it everytime you store something and decode it every time you pull something from it. it's unclear why you're using localstorage in the first place.. it sounds like you're just using to pass values around, which is not what localstorage is for.

Comment: I'm just experimenting by making an offline app that can store a few values. Not more than 10. The local storage will only hold the ID's of these 10 divs and then remove them at a later stage.

If it's not the best solution, then I'm always open for pointers.